# firebase phone authentication doest not sending SMS in traditional chinese language

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, localization

I am using the firebase phone authentication, but it doest not sending SMS in traditional chinese language. It works in english and simple chinese language.

Any one know why and how?

I hope firebase phone authentication can be work at sending SMS in traditional chinese language.

Comment: var ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());    
    ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', uiConfig);
    // no matter the languageCode is null, or "zh-tw", "zh-TW", "zh_tw", all not work for traditonal chinese
 firebase.auth().languageCode = "zh_tw";

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to require is the script part of the language tag to be used.

The official tag would be **zh-HANT** for traditional Chinese characters, except for rare cases when it is meaningful to distinguish different countries.

If you need to specify Taiwan, then expand it to *zh-tw-HANT*.

See [Construction of Language Tags](https://www.w3.org/International/articles/language-tags/#rfc) from the W3C.